# Get checked values in another view with angularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have list of checkbox with button submit , and I when i click on submit, I have to get all checked values in other view table. I find a lot of answers, but they all propose to get values in the same view,but I need to get values in other view(ajoutFactAdmin2), how can I do that please. this is the code:

ajoutFactAdmin2.html

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="x in namesF3">

          <div class="col"><input type="checkbox" name="" ng-modal="x.selected" ng-checked="exist(x)" ng-click="toggleSelection(x)" ng-true-value="'{{x.CodeEnvoiColis}}'" ng-false-value="''" id="'{{x.CodeEnvoiColis}}'"></div>
          <div class="col" >{{x.CodeEnvoiColis}}</div>   
          <div class="col" width="20%">{{x.StatutColis}}  </div>
          <div class="col" width="20%">{{x.VilleDestColis}}</div> 

</div>

<div class="selectedcontent">
            <h3> Selected Names </h3>
            <p ng-repeat = "selectedName in selected"> {{selectedName.CodeEnvoiColis}} </p>
</div>
          <a class="button button-info"   ng-click="toggleSelection(x)"  href="#/ajoutFactAdmin2" style="background-color:#1627C0;float: right;">Ajouter</a>
```

app.js :

```
$scope.selected = [];
           $scope.namesF3 = [];
          $scope.exist = function(item){
            return $scope.selected.indexOf(item) > -1;
          }

          $scope.toggleSelection = function(item){
             var x = [];
            var idx = $scope.selected.indexOf(item);
            if(idx > -1){
                 $scope.selected.splice(idx, 1);
            }
             else{
                 $scope.selected.push(item);
             }

          }
```

Comment: use `$rootScope`

Comment: Thank you, should I replace every $scope with $rootScope please?

Comment: try to use some storage like local or session or services

Comment: Can you exlpain how can I do  please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are mainly 3 ways to achieve this

1. local storage/session storage:

> ```
> To set value in local storage:
>
> localStorage.setItem("key","value");
>
> To get value:
>
> localStorage.getItem("key");
> ```

2. Factory/Service

> ```
> angular.module('app').factory('tempStorageService',function(){
>   var data={};
>   return{
>     setData:function(tempData){
>       data=tempData;
>     },
>     getData:function(){
>       return data;
>     }
>   }
> })
> ```

3. $rootScope

> `$rootScope.tempData = YourData;`

I would prefer to go with localstorage option because if you refresh the browser the data that is stored using factory or with $rootscope vanishes.

Comment: Thank you, how can I call this storage in my .html file , and what's the value I should put please because I have just a "push" in the code without saving the data. Thank you

Comment: Thanks , I did it  with rootScope. Thanks a lot